# How we can install Ubercart in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, ubercart

**Ubercart** module is the most popular **Drupal** E-Commerce platform. My question is how we can install and configure Ubercart module in Drupal.

Comment: Follow this link http://www.ubercart.org/docs/user/8075/installing_ubercart

Comment: Thanks Soni for this useful link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Ubercart documentation on drupal.org.

- [Installation docs](http://drupal.org/node/1312862).
- [Module docs](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/ubercart).

Comment: Thanks Muhammad Reda for these useful docs files.